# What is the effect of a scout standing at an enemy barracks?

Tags: civilization-board-game

A barracks add +2 to the owners Combat score and 2 Trade.
A scout allows you to effectively block or steal the benefits of an opponent's buildings by standing on them.

When I have a scout on an opponent's barracks what happens with the Combat score bonus?

- Do I steal it? (His score:0 Mine:+2)
- He just loses it? (His score:0 Mine:0)
- Or nothing, I just get the trade? (His score:+2 Mine:0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Military bonuses can be blockaded, but not stolen. So you get the trade, but **nobody gets the combat advantage**.

Source [Blockading a Great General (Board Game Geek)](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/6011749#6011749), from the the designer

> Military bonuses CAN be blockaded, however, scouts CANNOT steal
>   military bonuses (military bonuses weren't originally icons, and I'm
>   pretty sure that could be game breaking).
>
> Scouts can send home anything they're on top of except wonder
>   abilities and military bonuses (even in another player's outskirts,
>   even on top of a wonder, building, or great person).